# PayPal Pay() method in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I am using PayPal Pay() method but it is returning error response -

[ErrorID] => 550001
[Message] => You do not have permission to execute this payment implicitly

Can anyone help me? I am using angelleye paypal library for codeigniter.

Thank You

Comment: What's in Pay() method? use CI_Merchant if you're not already doing so, it has many gateways including paypal.

Comment: API asking for $config['DeviceID'] = $config['Sandbox'] ? '' : 'PRODUCTION_DEVICE_ID_GOES_HERE';

Where i can get this device id ? paypal only gives API Username, password, signature and Application id.

Comment: This is the first time I hear about Application id, I only used User/Pass/Signature anyway I still suggest that you use CI Merchant: http://ci-merchant.org (that's what I use for all sorts of payments)

Answer (score 0):

is `CI_Merchant` library has an option to payment without redirecting paypal site ?

i found this only,

`$this->merchant->load('paypal_express');`

but it redirects to paypal site.

Comment: Asking questions inside answer is not good. Try to avoid that